# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Laravel on server

Tags: php, laravel

Anyone help me to prevent this error on the server, localhost works fine.
I did not find the error even if I searched.

[this is the error every time used the application, cookies problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e70Tz.png)

my code on routes

```
Route::auth();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');


    Route::get('/users','UsersController@index');
    Route::get('/users/create','UsersController@create');
    Route::post('/users/store','UsersController@store');
    Route::get('/users/list_data','UsersController@list_data');});
```

Is the problem with the server? or my code?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Usually, there's somehow a dead-loop made thus caused ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, check your rules and simply them if possible

Comment: Sir @CKWong how to find the rules? sorry newbie

Comment: Which URL does that happen on?

Comment: usually on create and store url

Comment: Try moving '/' url out of `auth` middleware

Comment: Sir @devk is working, thank you :)

Comment: Sir @devk still have cookies :(